# The difference between "should + to be" and "should + be"

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I'm often facing a situation where "should + to be" form takes place. But from Grammar modal verb "should" takes a verb without particle "to".
Here examples of cases:

"should + to be":

> The notification should to be sent by registered mail. [source](https://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/env/documents/2007/eia/wg.1/ece.mp.eia.wg.1.2007.6.e.pdf)
>
> Internal dialogue to that and broader ends should to be fostered. [source](https://unispal.un.org/DPA/DPR/unispal.nsf/0/9538DBDA6010327285257479004B05E7)

"should + be":

> Both were unacceptable and should be rejected.
>
> Itinerants should be treated like all other Dutch citizens. [source (pdf)](http://docstore.ohchr.org/SelfServices/FilesHandler.ashx?enc=6QkG1d%2FPPRiCAqhKb7yhsll878jPTqqtS7jCMBGC1jq6GZl6jqGQmjWQrUGRqDetqPpWvjyif%2F54Z6D%2F70aPk8U8SUjWPKZsRUQdPW%2Bhh1lm8d0P0pxR1B6q5YpVPLiE)

The question is what is the difference between 2 cases?

Comment: The first two sentences  are ungrammatical. Can you tell us their source?

Comment: There are a lot of examples. You can find those having typed "should to be" in the search box of Google search engine on the news tab

Comment: Well, that's surprising! I have never encountered the passive construction "_should to be_ + past participle" before . But there are indeed examples in Google that appear to have been written by native speakers. I'm interested to know what's going on here.

Comment: I'd put money on people using a thesaurus incorrectly; "ought to" and "need to" are perfectly valid, but "should to" is never correct.

Comment: "Ought to be" or "sure to be" are fairly common, but on the few occasions I've read "should to be" I've taken it to be a typo, or some odd dialect.

Comment: It might well be a feature of some local dialect of Indian or Indonesian or Japanese English, influenced by a local teacher whose belief in rules was greater than their knowledge of them. There are millions of such speech groups around the world. It's unlikely to become a worldwide vogue, however, since the trend in English is to delete markers, not to add them.

Answer (score 5):

"Should to" is never correct.

> Modal verbs are followed by the infinitive of another verb without to. The exceptions are ought to and used to. (Source: [Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/should))